# Cloning instance - Original kernel not available when creating AMI

Tags: kernel, snapshot, amazon-ami, clone

I have a EC2 Ubuntu server on Amazon cloud and I'm trying to clone an instance "X" by creating a snapshot of the instance and creating an AMI from that snapshot.
The problem is: When creating the AMI, the Kernel used in the instance "X" is not available and if I choose another one, the server isn't booting correctly.

Steps that I've done
-Kernel ID of instance "X" is aki-825ea7eb
-The default kernel was choose at installation time for instance "X"
-Created a snapshot of the instace "X" root volume
-Create AMI from that snapshot ( try to choose the kernel aki-825ea7eb, but it's not available.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Problem Solved. The Arch selected was not the right one, so the Kernel was obviously not available.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, but unfortunately not the same easy solution.  I'm trying to migrate an EBS-backed Ubuntu server from East-1a to West (Oregon), but the aki is not available (aki-427d952b).  Just to make sure, I tried both architectures, but it's just not there.  Are kernel ids region-specific?

Comment: Please do not answer a question with a "me too" answer, its not helpful.